# WCF Sporadically slow with small data

Tags: wcf, performance

I have a WCF Service that is hosted through a custom application, as well as a custom client application that talks to the service.

The client itself deals with "customers", which are large blocks of information, as well as "comments" which are very small blocks of information.

There are approximately 40 people using the client and server at any one time. The performance on everything is very respectable, EXCEPT for one thing.

While working on a "customer" file, a staff member will almost always write a small comment that is saved off immediately - The comment may be "Spoke to customer about recent email", to give you an example of size.

Most (let's call it 90%) of the time, saving this information takes about two-tenths of a second. Sometimes, for no reason I have been able to find, it will take upwards of 30.

Bringing down large amounts of information never take anywhere near that long, and while I can replicate it (simply by entering 10-15 comments in a row), I can't actually find the problem.

This only happens on the production server by the way, never my development machine.

Any and all suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: These issues are very hard to diagnose, especially if you can't find any similarities or circumstances when this happens. This is hard to figure out for you with the code infront of you and next to impossible for us away from your code, your environment etc. - as long as you can't give us more information as to WHEN and WHY it's slow, we can only guess - at best....

Comment: Does your service do a lot of synchronous I/O - database requests and so on?  The problem may not be related to this specific operation at all, could just be that the service is heavily-loaded with blocking calls.

Comment: I agree that this is extremely difficult to diagnose, and believe me, if I had anything else to give you in relation to the issue. 

I did think it might be a DNS issue (slow resolution times), but I ruled that out. I also thought it might be something like a synchronous i/o issue, but thus far my tests haven't revealed anything.

And as I said, it's ONLY with this very, very small bit. If I open and close a client file repeatedly (which might be 1 megabyte in side, instead of say, 40 characters) it works perfectly, every time.

Again, suggestions are very welcome.